# Is it unnecessary to create additional indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-indexes

If I have a unique key on a column, would that make it unnecessary to have an additional index on the same column?

What if it is a multi-column unique key? Would that make it unnecessary to have an additional index on the FIRST column in the unique index column list?

There are similar questions on SO, but I wanted to get a definitive answer in this narrower context.

Comment: Ok fine. I will give you very specific answer, but later don't ask for further explanation. I have already mentioned, the word `(un)necessary` can differ on scenario. But, it seems like you are expecting answer in Yes and No only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have a unique key on a column, would that make it unnecessary to have an additional index on the same column?

Yes. `UNIQUE KEY` implicitly creates an index.

> What if it is a multi-column unique key? Would that make it unnecessary to have an additional index on the FIRST column in the unique index column list?

Yes. Any query that needs to search the first column can use the multi-column index.

By analogy, if I ask you to search the telephone book for people named "Smith, Sarah" it's like you search a compound index with two columns. If I ask you to use the same telephone book to search for people with last name "Smith" the sort order of the first column still helps, even though you don't need to search the second column.

Answer (score 1):

> would that make it unnecessary to have an additional index on the same
>   column?

Yes.

> What if it is a multi-column unique key?

Yes, it is fine to have few more indexes along with unique indexes.

---

**==Detailed Explanation==**

You should keep in mind that each time you perform DML on your table. It has to restructure your indexes. So, this totally depends, on what are you are achieving and what you are ready to compromise.

Assuming, you are working of some database, whose query performance (`SELECT`) is slow. Now, you thought of creating index, which eventually improved some performance. So, you thought, it was necessary to have this index.

Later, after some day, you started observing slowness when performing any DML operations on same table. Now, depending on what you are ready to comprise. This can be defined as (un)necessary for you.

**[8.3 Optimization and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html)**

> Although it can be tempting to create an indexes for every possible
>   column used in a query, ***unnecessary indexes waste space and waste time
>   for MySQL to determine which indexes to use. Indexes also add to the
>   cost of inserts, updates, and deletes because each index must be
>   updated.*** You must find the right balance to achieve fast queries using
>   the optimal set of indexes.

Comment: @stepanian If I'm not wrong then this was your question `would that make it unnecessary to have an additional index on the same column?` right ? If so, then read highlighted and bold font.

Comment: @stepanian short answer is "highlighted in bold". Doesn't matter what and where. It is costly. If you read it carefully(slowly). Then you understand its actual meaning

Comment: @stepanian It is unnecessary if you making on same column, because behind the scene it uses B-Tree for `(PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT)`. But, if it  is on different column, then again you will be compromising something.

Comment: Thanks. For the second answer, by "Yes", do you mean having an additional index on the first column is unnecessary as it is "covered" by the unique multi-column index?

Comment: @stepanian there will be separate index maintained for first column. So, even multi-column covers same column again. Then, it will ok. I had given proper explanation. But, you weren't interested in reading the use cases.

Comment: @stepanian any reason for reverting your upvote ? Even I don't care, but I just wanted to know the reason

Comment: It was inadvertent. Sorry.